# Apache Nutch on Windows

Tags: windows, cygwin, nutch

Has anyone tryed to install Nutch on Windows? I'm following this installation guide: http://zillionics.com/resources/articles/NutchGuideForDummies.htm

After a few bumps I'm stuck trying to run the crawler. It gives me this error:

bin/nutch: line 15: syntax error near unexpected token '$'in\r''
'in/nutch: line 15: 'case "'uname'" in

Apparently I need to install the uname utility in cygwin but I can't find it anywhere. Does anyone know in which package is it in or if there another way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I've found the solution to this: uname was installed that was not the problem. The weird thing is that the shell scripts are in DOS text format instead of Unix text format. Using the 'd2u' command to convert this files fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't that uname is missing.  The problem is that the nutch script has incorrect line termination.  I do the following:

1) open nutch in vi

2) :set ff=unix

3) :wq